# Invoking BBM Video/Audio from Workspace application

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, bb-messenger, blackberry-c++

I am able to invoke BBM chat from workspace, but I cannot invoke Video/Audio chat. Is this available, or is it restricted?

Here is my invocation code.

```
InvokeManager invokeManager;
InvokeRequest request;
request.setTarget("sys.service.videochat");
request.setAction("bb.action.OPEN");
QString data_str = "dest="+pin+"&video=" + video;
QByteArray data = data_str.toUtf8();
qDebug() << "=========BBM Video Data: " + data;
request.setData(data);
invokeManager.invoke(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoking BBM Audio and Video from the work perimeter is not supported.  It designed to be invoked from the personal perimeter only.

Comment: What about this? http://bizblog.blackberry.com/2013/11/bbm-integration-for-the-work-space/